Solving $\sin(-x)+\cot(x)=1$
For our homework, our teacher assigned us an extremely demanding problem.$$\sin(-x)+\cot(x)=1$$ This problem may seem easy but the answer is incredibly complex. There are two sets of (real) solutions, here they are: $$x=2\left(\pi n+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(-1-\frac{4\cdot2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{13+3\sqrt{33}}}+\sqrt[3]{2\left(13+3\sqrt{33}\right)}\right)\right)\right),n\in \mathbb{Z},\tan(x)\neq0$$ and
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\left(4\pi n-\pi\right),n\in \mathbb{Z}$$ I have no idea how to attain either of these solutions. If someone can help me get either of these solutions with clear steps, that would be incredibly helpful.

At least you should be able to find the second set of solutions?

Try pulling out the negative sign from the sine function and square both sides. You should be able to get a cubic equation in terms of $\cos$

Okay thanks, I did that and it doesn't work. For all of our work we aren't allowed to use a calculator or calculus, and there is an extraneous solution where that above complex solution is written in terms of arccos, and then you know I get something like plus minus arccos(...) + 2pin, it's very heavy to prove that extraneous solution is false though without calculus, at least the way I did.

Hint
I suppose that the first formula came from the tangent half-angle substitution
$$f(x)=\cot(x)-\sin(x)-1$$
$$x=2\tan^{-1}(t) \quad \implies \quad g(t)=\frac{(t+1) \left(t^3+t^2+3 t-1\right)}{2 t \left(t^2+1\right)}$$
Using the hyperbolic solution, the real root of the cubic is just
$$t=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}  \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{8
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{3}$$ This looks (at least to me) abit nicer.
